# Difference between standard ninject and ninject.web.mvc in an MVC3 project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I understand some of the functionality of Ninject and have been able to use it for IoC.

When I go to add a reference to Ninject to a project in VS2010, using NuGet, I see other Ninject extensions in the list.  Specifically Ninject.MVC3.  Also on the Ninject website under extensions ( http://www.ninject.org/extensions.html ) I see Ninject.Web.Mvc.

If I am creating MVC3 applications do I need to use this extension of Ninject?  Does my basic use of Ninject for IoC with classes/interfaces require anything beyond the standard library?

What is the difference between Ninject and Ninject.MVC3/Ninject.Web.Mvc in an MVC3 project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ninject.web.mvc` is a ninject (core) complement for the ASP MVC (3) applications. Basically - you should use it, when you want to use Ninject in an ASP MVC project.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/MVC3):

> This extension allows integration between the Ninject core and ASP.NET
>   MVC projects. To use it, just make your HttpApplication (typically in
>   Global.asax.cs) extend NinjectHttpApplication:

MVC 3 extension contains the crucial methods to wire up the DI composition root into MVC application - it means that Ninject will be responsible for instantiating your controllers, that has dependencies on other components (Ninjects 'overrides' the use of `DefaultControllerFactory` which is only able to create controllers with parameterless constructors).

*In the documentation there are mentioned two methods, [how to do it](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Setting-up-an-MVC3-application): either extending the `NinjectHttpApliaction` in `global.asax` or using the `NinjectWebCommon` class inside the `App_Start` folder.*

There is also [ninject.web.common](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.common/wiki) extension, which is required for `ninject.web.mvc`. It contains e.g. the definition of `InRequestScope`.

Comment: Are you saying that ninject.web.mvc allows ninject to interact with the MVC specific classes/interfaces of an MVC app, whereas standard ninject doesn't support them?

I probably need to look more into the various reasons and examples for Ninject handling controllers in an MVC app.

Comment: Not really. The key thing is that `ninject.web.mvc` provides extended controller factory that is able to inject dependencies (according to bindings defined in composition root - usually global.asax) in controllers (using the `ninject.core`). So you do not need to somehow pass an instance of ninject `kernel` through your application - which would smell with service locator pattern - and can enjoy the advantages of (constructor) dependency injection.